# DS1683 oscillator accuracy?

Tags: datasheet, time

I'm working on a project that includes a [DS1683](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1683.pdf) elapsed-time and event recorder chip. This chip has an internal oscillator that allows it to measure elapsed time, but I can't find any description in the datasheet about what kind of oscillator it is, or more importantly, how accurate it is.

Is there anyone who has worked with this chip and can answer these questions?

Comment: Sounds like a question best directed at your friendly local Maxim FAE! Note, there is mention of a low  TempCo RC osc, but a distinct lack of accuracy spec as you’ve mentioned. Maybe they didn’t want to scare us.

Comment: The time event minimum, nominal, and maximum implies 5%.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Ah, there it is! Much worst than I would have hoped, but presumably that's the very worst case over the full range of PVT (process, voltage and temperature). The FPGA includes a Microblaze running freeRTOS, so it might be interesting to set up a task that monitors the DS1683 accuracy relative to the CPU crystal under our actual operating conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Kartman's suggestion, I searched Maxim's (now ADI's) knowledge base and came across [this article](https://maximsupport.microsoftcrmportals.com/en-us/knowledgebase/article/000098717), which says:

> Unfortunately the accuracy for these two devices was never measured for a worst case scenario. The 2% or 20,000ppm for both devices was the intended design across temperature so the worst case shouldn't be much more than the 2% value, if at all. The two devices were intended for long term time measurement and not down to the second accuracy.

DKNguyen spotted the following entry in the datasheet:

```
     PARAMETER          SYMBOL  CONDITIONS   MIN   TYP   MAX   UNITS
   Time Event Increment  t_EI    (Note 1)   237.5  250  262.5   ms
```

which implies a range of ±5%. Presumably that's the very worst case over the full range of PVT (process, voltage and temperature).

The FPGA includes a Microblaze running freeRTOS, so it might be interesting to set up a task that monitors the DS1683 accuracy relative to the CPU crystal under our actual operating conditions.

Comment: That's a poor explanation from ADI and doesn't give any confidence; I would have expected better. It sounds like this part isn't really supported anymore and could even have had some defects that are not documented.

Answer (score 1):

That's unfortunate - nowhere does the data sheet show what could be considered the primary performance characteristic of this IC !

It does say it's a trimmed RC oscillator. It is possible to build those with better than 1 % stability - that would be a good estimate (perhaps 2 % for margin).

Note the DS1682 which is similar has this in its datasheet: "Calibrated, Temperature-Compensated RC Time Base Accurate to 2% Typical". It's not obvious if removal from the DS1683 datasheet is an error or an indication of problems meeting that 2 % guideline.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I finally did notice the statement about "factory-calibrated, low-temperature-coefficient
RC time base" in the very first sentence of the datasheet shortly after I posted the question. But the lack of any statement at all about accuracy is worrying. I didn't actually do the PCB-level hardware design on this project -- I'm just responsible for the FPGA logic and low-level software drivers. I guess I'm going to have to assume that whoever selected this part decided that it was going to meet their needs.